# Why is not the system call signal() calling the handler?

Tags: c, linux, signals, ipc

I'm trying to handle the signals SIGTERM and SIGUSR1 between 4 process (3 children + 1 father) but I have no idea why the `signal()` is not calling the handler. Could someone help me?

That's the output like I expect:

```
pid of father of all: 13192
The father 13192 is waiting to all children die to too
Child1: pid = 13196 - parent's pid: 13192
Child2: pid = 13197 - parent's pid: 13192
Child3: pid = 13198 - parent's pid: 13192
Sending user signal
user signal sent
Into the interrupt_handler
The child1 13196 is going to be killed immediately
The child2 13197 is going to be killed later
The child2 13197 is going to kill itself now
Child3: pid = 13198 - parent's pid: 13192
Sending user signal
user signal sent
Into the interrupt_handler
The child3 13198 is going to be killed immediately
```

That's the output I'm getting:

```
pid of father of all: 13192
The father 13192 is waiting to all children die to too
Child1: pid = 13196 - parent's pid: 13192
Child2: pid = 13197 - parent's pid: 13192
Child3: pid = 13198 - parent's pid: 13192
Sending user signal
user signal sent
Child1: pid = 13196 - parent's pid: 13192
Child2: pid = 13197 - parent's pid: 13192
Child3: pid = 13198 - parent's pid: 13192
Sending user signal
user signal sent
Child1: pid = 13196 - parent's pid: 13192
...
```

As you can see, the interrupt_handler has not been called to handle the signal. That's the issue.

Here's my whole code:

```
#include <errno.h>              // errno and error codes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>             // for fork()
#include <stddef.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <sys/types.h>          // for wait()
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>            // for all IPC function calls
#include <sys/shm.h>            // for shmget(), shmat(), shmctl()
#include <sys/sem.h>            // for semget(), semop(), semctl()
#include <sys/wait.h>           // for wait()
#include <sys/unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>             // for kill(), sigsuspend(), others

pid_t child1, child2, child3;

int count_tens=0;

void interrupt_handler(int signal){

    printf("Into the interrupt_handler\n");

    if (signal==SIGUSR1)
    {
        count_tens++;

        if(count_tens==1)
        {
            printf("The child1 %d is going to be killed immediately\n",getpid());
            if(!kill(child1,SIGKILL))
                perror("Did not kill (1)");//kills child1
            printf("The child2 %d is going to be killed later\n",getpid());
            if(!kill(child2,SIGTERM))
                perror("Did not kill (2)");//let the child2 goes through interrupt_handler

        } else if(count_tens==2)
        {
            printf("The child3 %d is going to be killed immediately\n",getpid());
            //main(); //restart application
            raise(SIGKILL); //child3 dies. At this point all children have died.

        }
    }

    if (signal==SIGTERM){
        printf("The child2 %d is going to kill itself now\n",getpid());
        raise(SIGKILL);
    }
}

int main(){

    if ((signal(SIGTERM, interrupt_handler) == SIG_ERR) || (signal(SIGUSR1, interrupt_handler) == SIG_ERR)) {
        printf("Error while setting a signal handler\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    child1=fork();
    if (child1<0) { perror("fork"); exit(errno);}
    if(child1==0){
        while(1){
            sleep(4);
            printf("Child1: pid = %d - parent's pid: %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
        }
    }

    child2=fork();
    if(child2<0) { perror("fork"); exit(errno);}
    if(child2==0){
        while(1){
            sleep(5);
            printf("Child2: pid = %d - parent's pid: %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
        }
    }

    child3=fork();
    if(child3<0) { perror("fork"); exit(errno);}
    if(child3==0){
        while(1){
            sleep(6);
            printf("Child3: pid = %d - parent's pid: %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
            printf("Testando: Child1 pid = %d, Child2 pid = %d, Child3 pid = %d\n",child1,child2,child3);
                printf("Sending user signal\n");
                kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
                printf("user signal sent\n");
        }
    }

    printf("pid of father of all: %d\n",getpid());
    printf("The father %d is waiting to all children die to too\n",getpid());
    waitpid(child3, NULL, 0); // PARENT blocks until 3th CHILD ends
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When `wait()` is interrupted by a signal, it returns `-1`, with `errno` set to `EINTR`. So the `while` loop at the end will end after the first signal.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for replying. I commented the line while(wait(NULL)!=-1); and now when I run the program my ubuntu log out automatically. It seems my application crashes the SO. How should I fix? I have limited knowledge of these things. I would appreciate too much your help. tks!

Comment: If you comment out the loop, the parent process has nothing else to do after it forks all the children, so it exits.

Comment: Change it to `while (wait(NULL) == -1);` so it will keep waiting after the interrupts. Or use `sigaction()` and specify `SA_RESTART` so it restarts automatically.

Comment: @Barmar, instead of `while (wait(NULL) == -1);` or `sigaction()` I felt better using `waitpid(child3, NULL, 0);`. At this point the program should work with no excuses! But the `signal()` still is not calling the `interrupt_handler`. Now I belive the problem is not at the wait's line :´(. More suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, there's more to it than that, since that only explains why it doesn't repeat, it doesn't explain why the first signal isn't caught.

Comment: this kind of line: `if(!kill(child1,SIGKILL))` is not correct.  `kill()` returns 0 on success,  So this 'if' statement is backwards.  Suggest: `if( kill(child1,SIGKILL) )`  here is an excerpt from the man page: " On success (at least one signal was sent), zero is returned.  On error,
       -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately."

Comment: the man page for `signal()` says: "The behavior of signal() varies across UNIX versions, and has also var‐
       ied historically across different versions of Linux.   Avoid  its  use:
       use sigaction(2) instead.  See Portability below.
"

Comment: this kind of line: `if (child1<0) { perror("fork"); exit(errno);}` will have problems because a return value is actually only a byte in size and errno is a 4 byte integer

Answer (score 0):

The handler will be executed by the process which received the signal.

To kill the child3 `kill(child3,SIGKILL)` may be used instead of`raise(SIGKILL);`.

At the first signal in this program, the handler will be called by the father because the father received the first signal (`SIGUSR1`) so doing `raise(SIGKILL);` the father is killing itself.

Here's whole code:

```
#include <errno.h>              // errno and error codes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>             // for fork()
#include <stddef.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <sys/types.h>          // for wait()
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>            // for all IPC function calls
#include <sys/shm.h>            // for shmget(), shmat(), shmctl()
#include <sys/sem.h>            // for semget(), semop(), semctl()
#include <sys/wait.h>           // for wait()
#include <sys/unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>             // for kill(), sigsuspend(), others

pid_t child1, child2, child3;

int count_tens=0;

void interrupt_handler(int signal){

    printf("Into the interrupt_handler\n");

    if (signal==SIGUSR1)
    {
        count_tens++;

        if(count_tens==1)
        {
            printf("The child1 %d is going to be killed immediately\n",child1);
            if(kill(child1,SIGKILL)==-1)
                perror("Did not kill (1)");//kills child1
            printf("The child2 %d is going to be killed later\n",child2);
            if(kill(child2,SIGTERM)==-1)
                perror("Did not kill (2)");//let the child2 goes through interrupt_handler

        } else if(count_tens==2)
        {
            printf("The child3 %d is going to be killed immediately\n",child3);
            //main(); //restart application
            if(kill(child3,SIGKILL)==-1)
                perror("Did not kill (3)");//kills child3. At this point all children have died.
        }
    }

    if (signal==SIGTERM){
        printf("The child2 %d is going to be killed now\n",getpid());
        if(raise(SIGKILL)==-1)
            perror("Did not kill (4)");//let the child2 goes through interrupt_handler
    }
}

int main(){

    if ((signal(SIGTERM, interrupt_handler) == SIG_ERR) || (signal(SIGUSR1, interrupt_handler) == SIG_ERR)) {
        printf("Error while setting a signal handler\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    child1=fork();
    if (child1<0) { perror("fork"); exit(errno);}
    if(child1==0){
        while(1){
            sleep(4);
            printf("Child1: pid = %d - parent's pid: %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
        }
    }

    child2=fork();
    if(child2<0) { perror("fork"); exit(errno);}
    if(child2==0){
        while(1){
            sleep(5);
            printf("Child2: pid = %d - parent's pid: %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
        }
    }

    child3=fork();
    if(child3<0) { perror("fork"); exit(errno);}
    if(child3==0){
        while(1){
            sleep(6);
            printf("Child3: pid = %d - parent's pid: %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
            printf("Sending user signal\n");
            if(kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1)==-1)
                perror("Did not kill (5)");//kills child3
                printf("user signal sent\n");
        }
    }

    printf("pid of father of all: %d\n",getpid());
    printf("The father %d is waiting to all children die to too\n",getpid());
    while(wait(NULL)!=-1);
    printf("The father %d is going to die\n",getpid());
    exit(0);
}
```